# user.find is not a function, in mongoose model in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

`user.find` is not a function, my model is:

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    f_name : String,
    l_name : String
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('user', UserSchema, 'user');
```

Comment: So how/where are you using `user`?

Comment: show your contoller . where you are using find()

Answer (score 1):

> I think there is some declaration mistake here try this:

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    f_name : {type: String},
    l_name : {type: String}
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

It might be possible that you are querying `'user.find'` before your model is actually registered.

Please post the exact senario how are you using it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original declaration: you don't need to use `type` in this case, and the third (`'user'`) argument is to state which MongoDB collection name to use for the model.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the schema model. The error will be present in the code where you used User. You hadn't mentioned that in your query.

The very basic thing about find() is that, find() function belongs to a model, not to a schema. So you need to run a model and then use find on it.